# Rank nullity failure

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm doing a problem with the matrix 
$$A=\left[\begin{array}{cccc} 0&3&3&3\\0&0&0&0\\ 0&1&0&1 \end{array}\right].$$ I found that the column space has dimension two and basis $$\left\{ \left[\begin{array}{c} 3\\0\\1\\\end{array}\right],\left[\begin{array}{c} 3\\0\\0\\\end{array}\right]\right\},$$ while the null space has dimension 1, and basis $$\left\{ \left[\begin{array}{c} 0\\1\\0\\-1 \end{array}\right]\right\}.$$

But this seems to contradict the rank-nullity theorem, since $1+2\neq 4$. I suspect this is because the rightmost column is all 0, but I'm not sure. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: No, the explanation is that you simply made an error in your calculations. Regarding what part is wrong, a hint: When I teach linear algebra I always make certain to give a problem like this, where one of the columns is zero...

Comment: Ah, is it that the nullspace has dimension two because the first coordinate can take any value? The other basis vector is (1,0,0,0)?

Comment: Yes. Seeing this is good. It's also important to see how this follows from the algorithm you know for finding a basis for the null space...